# Problema con combinación de información de múltiples peticiones a una API desde express

Tags: javascript, api, express, axios

tengo un problema al intentar combinar multiples peticiones que hago a una api, intenté hacerlo con un Promise.all
Adjunto mi código para que se den una idea

```js
let Videojuegos = [1, 2]

let VideoJuegos = (await Promise.all(Videojuegos.map(async e => {
  let VGames = (await axios.get(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=${KEY_API}&page=${e}`)).data.results;
  VGames = await VGames.map(el => {
    return {
      name: el.name
    }
  })
  return VGames
})))
```

Lo que me devuelve en express haciendole un res.json(VideoJuegos) es un array con 2 arrays dentro.

```
[
 [...], [...]
]
```

Está la información ahí (son 20 elementos por cada array), pero al querer combinar los 2 arrays con un .flat() o un combine lo que me devuelve es un array pero solo con 15 elementos.
Al hacer un console.log(VideoJuegos.flat()) me dan los 40 elementos, pero en la petición get solo me muestra 15. Si alguien sabe alguna solución se lo agradecería

Comment: No entiendo muy bien todo el contexto que estas realizando, pero por que no haces un simple `videoJuegosPlanos=[...videoJuegos[0], ...videoJuegos[1] ]` ?

Comment: Hola, gracias por la idea. ambién lo hice y me sigue mostrando 15 elementos, los mismo si solo intento mostrar VideoJuegos[0]. Al hacer la petición get solo me muestra 15 elementos y no los 20 que en teoría sería lo correcto

Comment: Puede que el map te este dando un error? Haz console.log en cada paso para detectar la fuga.

Comment: No creo, cambié el código para no usar el map

El tema es que si se muestran todos por consola (los 40 elementos), pero al hacer la petición solo me devuelve 15 elementos
@Legna

Comment: Puede que no te este devolviendo un json?. Intenta hacer un JSON.parse sobre los datos crudos.

Comment: Hice un JSON.parse(VideoJuegos), lo intenté también al retornar el valor que devuelve cada petición en el promise.all   --->  return JSON.parse(VGames) y me sale lo mismo.
Da este error : Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: De esta linea ` VGames = await VGames.map(el => {` quita el `await`, esta de más.

Comment: Si, tienes razón que está de más. 
Sigue con el mismo problema, solo muetra 15 elementos al hacerle un get, no sé si hay otra forma de resolver este problema y no estoy en la correcta forma de encararlo

Comment: Usa stackblitz para replicar el caso y poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

No debes de combinar `async` con `Promise.all`. `await` resuelve la promesa y te devuelve los datos mientras que `Promise.all` espera una respuesta sin resolver.

Una aproximación a lo que quieres puede ser esta (El fragmento es funcional, solo agrega tu llave en el prompt) :

```js
let Videojuegos = [1, 2];
const PROMESAS = [];

let KEY_API = prompt("Ingresa KEY_API");

Videojuegos.forEach(async(i) => {
  let PROMESA = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=${KEY_API}&page=${i}`)
      .then((respuesta) => {
        let datos = respuesta.data.results.map((el) => {
          return el.name;
          // return {
          //   name: el.name,
          // };
        });

        return resolve(datos);
      })
      .catch((e) => reject(e));
  });

  PROMESAS.push(PROMESA);
});

Promise.all(PROMESAS)
  .then((datos) => {
    let datosUnidos = datos.reduce((anterior, actual) => {
      anterior.push(...actual);

      return anterior;
    }, []);

    console.log({
      datosUnidos
    });
   //Aqui lo pones. La conexión no finaliza hasta que hagas
   // res.send ó res.json  
    return res.json(datosUnidos)
   
  })
  .catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-lj3cqm?file=index.js). Solo agrega tu llave.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de escribir el código, lo entiendo perfectamente. Lo único que tengo duda es cómo saco datosUnidos, ya que necesito hacerle un res.json(datosUnidos) para retornar la información ya que no puedo sacarlo de ahí por el scope. Muchas gracias

Comment: Donde esta el console.log, haz el res.send. Modifico la pregunta para que lo veas.

Comment: Lo revisé de arriba a abajo y encontré el error en mi código gracias a tu aporte. Tenía una función de paginado que no recordaba y eso es lo que me seguia dando error. Al final el código que hice y el que hiciste estan bien. Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Excelente. Me imagine que algo así  fuera, pero al no conocer el código completo lo mejor que se puede hacer es un ejemplo que de el resultado. Ayuda a aclarar la mente.

Comment: Si, tienes razón, al estar en express no metí todo el código por que pensé que no era relevante lo demás. Aprendí de tu código también así que muchas gracias por ayudarme